# Failed to install selenium on Ubuntu with Python3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, selenium

I want to use selenium on Ubuntu with Python3. I run the following commands according to instructions:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo pip-3.2 install -U selenium
Downloading/unpacking selenium
  Downloading selenium-2.37.2.tar.gz (2.6MB): 2.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package selenium

Installing collected packages: selenium
  Running setup.py install for selenium

Successfully installed selenium
Cleaning up...
```

But when I try to import selenium module in python3 I get an error:

```
@ubuntu:~$ python3

    Python 3.2.5 (default, Sep  7 2013, 16:55:10) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import selenium
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named selenium
```

Comment: Did you restart the terminal?

Comment: Will it run with python 2.7?

Comment: In my case it works with python (python3 also does not work)

Answer (score 5):

You can use selenium on Ubuntu with Python3 by following steps:

1. use `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` to install pip for python3
2. use `sudo python3 -m pip install -U selenium` to install selenium for python3